# Is there a way to check nodejs app alive using prometheus?

Tags: express, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'd like to use prometheus monitoring system to check my `nestjs` application

I have url like http://IP:PORT/test

Is that possible to check that url dead or alive using `prometheus`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prometheus: Check if an HTTP server is up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56850112/prometheus-check-if-an-http-server-is-up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use blackbox to check http or tcp
https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/blob/master/example.yml